# Coupled first order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I don't know how to solve this with Mathematica. I want to know if there is an analytical solution for any value of `m`?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {(y'[t])/y[t] + 3 a*x'[t]/x[t] == 
9 b*y[t]^(m - 1)*(x'[t]/x[t])^2, (x'[t]/x[t])^2 + k/x[t]^2 == 
1/3 (d + y[t]), x[1] == x0, y[1] == y0};
```

Comment: `I want if there is an analytical solution for any value of m`  well, V 13 can't solve it. doubt there is analytical solution for this. But you can ask at the math forum.

Comment: This second order system is autonomous, so it may be possible to reduce it to a first order system.  This, in itself, does not guarantee that it can be solved symbolically., of course.

Comment: Replacing $u=e^x,\,v=e^y$ leads to the first order ODE `u'[v] == -((E^(v + 2 u[v]) Sqrt[d + E^v - 3 E^(-2 u[v]) k])/(Sqrt[3] (3 b d E^(2 u[v]) (E^v)^m + 3 b E^(v + 2 u[v]) (E^v)^m - 9 b (E^v)^m k + Sqrt[3] a E^(v + 2 u[v]) Sqrt[d + E^v - 3 E^(-2 u[v]) k])))`, according to a `DSolve` stack trace of a `Solve` message. But `DSolve` cannot solve it.

Comment: I can get a solution in some special cases, but so far only for `k = 0`, which is probably unsatisfactory.  (E.g. `{m = 2, a = 1, d = 2, k = 0}`, `b` arbitrary.